# Solve $\left(\frac{1}{25\cdot26}+\frac{1}{26\cdot27}+\frac{1}{27\cdot28}+\frac{1}{28\cdot29}+\frac{1}{29\cdot30}\right)\cdot150+\frac{1}{x-1}=11$

Tags: contest-math

> Solve for $x$:
>   $$\left(\frac{1}{25\cdot26}+\frac{1}{26\cdot27}+\frac{1}{27\cdot28}+\frac{1}{28\cdot29}+\frac{1}{29\cdot30}\right)\cdot150+\frac{1}{x-1}=11$$

I have tried alot of things, but nothing seems to work. I imagine there is a really elegant solution that I just can't see. Please help, thanks!

Comment: $\displaystyle \frac{1}{n(n+1))} = \frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{n+1}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have

$$\frac 1{n(n+1)}=\frac 1n-\frac 1{n+1},$$

so you get a telescoping sum, which gives you

$$\left(\frac 1{25}-\frac 1{30}\right)\times 150+\frac 1{x-1}=11$$

so

$$\frac 5{5\times 150}\times 150 +\frac 1{x-1}=11$$

so

$$1+\frac 1{x-1}=11.$$

Finally, $\frac 1{x-1}=10$, so $x=\frac 1{10}+1=\frac {11}{10}$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: show that $$\left(\frac{1}{25\cdot 26}+...\frac{1}{29\cdot30}\right)\cdot 150=1$$

Comment: Wow man.. Really?

Comment: @N.S.JOHN        Really.